# Convert local coordinates to decimal latitude and longitude given a known 0,0 point

Tags: r, geospatial, latitude-longitude, spatial

I have data from a mapped region 100' x 100'.  The data is spatially distributed with local x,y coordinates where x ranges from 0-100 and y ranges from 0-100.  The actual location of my 0,0 point is known to be:

Latitude =  41.947901°

Longitude = -87.655815°

Can I convert my given 'local' coordinates to actual Lat/Long?

An x,y data.frame similar to the one I'm using can be developed from the following code:

```
xycords <- data.frame(x=rep(1:100,times=1,each=100),y=rep(1:100,times=100,each=1))
```

Comment: OK, my bad, old failing memory is corrected: ~0.11m http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/29544

Comment: And you need to account the earth http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2964/29544